# How to call python matplotlib in Qt C++ project?

Tags: python, c++, qt, matplotlib

Python matplotlib gives very nice figures. How to call python matplotlib in Qt C++ project? I'd like to put those figures in Qt dialogs and data are transferred via memory.

Comment: Must it be matplotlib? Qt has matching plotting libs too: you can take a look at [**QCustomPlot**](http://www.qcustomplot.com/) or [**Qwt**](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: @Tay2510 QCustomPlot and Qwt, which one is better? Thanks.

Comment: It depends. `QCustomPlot` is better in interactive plot but most of them are 2D plots. On the other hand, `Qwt` supports more complicated plots like 3D plots but less proficient at interactive plots.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a python script with function calls to matplotlib and add them as callback functions in your C++ code.

[This tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11805/Embedding-Python-in-C-C-Part-I) explains how this can be done.

I also recommend reading the documentation on [Python.h](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html).

Answer (score 1):

I would try using [matplotlib-cpp](https://github.com/lava/matplotlib-cpp). It is built to resemble the plotting API used by Matlab and matplotlib. Basically it is a C++ wrapper around matplotlib and it's header only. Keep in mind though that it does not provide all the matplotlib features from python.

Here is the initial example from GitHub:

```
#include "matplotlibcpp.h"
namespace plt = matplotlibcpp;
int main() {
    plt::plot({1,3,2,4});
    plt::show();
}
```

Compile

```
g++ minimal.cpp -std=c++11 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -lpython2.7
```

[image: Plot of the minimal example]

Comment: I don't think it is possible to integrate with qt as this issue implies https://github.com/lava/matplotlib-cpp/issues/115